# Extend bootstrap navbar, to the right only, dual color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar with 2 background colors, which is inside a container (see example). I want to extend it in blue to the right, but beyond the limit of the container it turns white again.

I have written a css solution which needs to be applied to all breakpoints (bootstrap)

Is there an easier way? (desktop sizes only)

This is without the extender to right:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  background-color: blue;
}

.navbar-default {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <div class="triangle"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I did:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
  background-color: blue;
 }
 .navbar-default {
  border: 0;
 }
 @media(min-width:768px){
  .extender {
   height: 50px;
   width: calc((100vw - 750px)/2 + 15px);
   background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 750px)/2) - 15px);
  }
 }
 @media(min-width:992px){
  .extender {
   height: 50px;
   width: calc((100vw - 970px)/2 + 15px);
   background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 970px)/2) - 15px);
  }
 }
 @media(min-width:1200px){
  .extender {
   height: 50px;
   width: calc((100vw - 1170px)/2 + 15px);
   background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 1170px)/2) - 15px);
  }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  <div class="extender"></div>
   </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
 </nav>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly you want, you want the `nav` bar to be blue in color

Comment: actually what i want is a navbar extending to the right like second example, but easier css, without calc() maybe

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
  background-color: blue;
 }
 .navbar-default {
  border: 0;
 }
 @media(min-width:768px){
  .extender {
   height: 50px;
   width: calc((100vw - 750px)/2 + 15px);
   background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 750px)/2) - 15px);
  }
 }
 @media(min-width:992px){
  .extender {
   height: 50px;
   width: calc((100vw - 970px)/2 + 15px);
   background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 970px)/2) - 15px);
  }
 }
 @media(min-width:1200px){
  .extender {
   height: 50px;
   width: calc((100vw - 1170px)/2 + 15px);
   background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 1170px)/2) - 15px);
  }
 }
  .navbar-header{background:blue;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
    </ul>
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  <div class="extender"></div>
   </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
 </nav>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```